# clang compiler is not working for 'opt' command

Tags: c++, clang, llvm

opt command not working for CLANG compiler, installed CLANG and LLVM, after I ran

```
clang++ -emit-llvm -S test.cpp -o prog.ll
```

it is working well and good but once I tried running the 'opt'

```
opt --dot-cfg prog.ll
```

I am getting the error as

```
'opt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.'
```

Comment: What platform are you on? What's your `clang` version?

Comment: check if opt is indeed installed then check if its path is in `PATH`

Comment: Clang version is 10.0.0, LLVM version is 12 and platform is Windows

Comment: Whatever you installed provided clang, but not opt, or provided opt in a location that's not in your PATH. You didn't specify either precisely what you installed, where you installed it or what your PATH is, so reproducing this would be tricky indeed.

Comment: I don't quite understand what you mean by LLVM version is 12 but Clang is 10. Could you add what/how you installed the LLVM toolchain and how are you obtaining those versions? Also, if you installed the toolchain from [here](https://github.com/llvm/llvm-project/releases/tag/llvmorg-12.0.0)(`LLVM-12.0.0-win64.exe`), surprisingly it doesn't ship with an `opt` tool.

Comment: a. We have to install LLVM from LLVM Download Page.

b. ‘Pre-Built Binaries’ and download Windows (64-bit) .sig and install it.

c. To compile the Open x64 Native tools Command prompt for VS …

d. Under CMD we have to “cd” to project folder.

f. To create new file we have to type in ‘echo > file name .c’

g. Open the file in any editor and write the code.

h. To check code from MS CL compiler ‘cl file_name .c’ if it runs without any error

i. To build the same code in CLANG type in the following command

clang -std=c17 -Wall -pedantic test.c

Comment: LLVM version means I had downloaded the LLVM of certain version from the website, Kindly refer the link from which I have downloaded https://releases.llvm.org/download.html#12.0.0

Comment: Please don't add details in comments. Instead [edit] the question to include that information.